# Adding new Routes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How can I add new routes in react JS using this existing code below?

I want a route that doesn't require authentication.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <SnackbarProvider
                maxSnack={5}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                autoHideDuration={3000}
              >
                <App history={history} runtime={runtime} />

              </SnackbarProvider>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </LanguageProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );
```

Thank you very much!

New learner here! So excited to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you you might already have [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) it means you should use [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) as well. Just add your routes in App component, [here you can find clear and good examples](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the basic routing example here:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Source](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)